# Unable to get the correct result sql plus

Tags: sql, oracle

I can't get the correct result, as the result shown. I want to SUM up the cost column but failed. 
The total fees should be sum of cost but when I group by it become 6000+. Any mistake I did?

```
Select  p.title, SUM(c.cost) as Total_Fees, c.cost
    from programmes p Inner Join courses c
        ON p.programme_id = c.programme_id 
    Inner join class_schedules cs
        ON c.course_id = cs.course_id AND c.semester = 4
    Inner join class_enrollments ce
        ON cs.schedule_id = ce.schedule_id 
    Inner Join students s
        ON ce.student_id = s.student_id and s.student_id = '13WAR1001'  
    GROUP BY p.title, c.cost;

            TITLE                                                                    TOTAL_FEES       COST
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ---------- ----------
Bachelor of Information Technology (Honours) in Internet Technology                     1728        576
Bachelor of Information Technology (Honours) in Internet Technology                     1353        451
Bachelor of Information Technology (Honours) in Internet Technology                     1184        592
Bachelor of Information Technology (Honours) in Internet Technology                     1800        600

    TITLE                                                                                                 COURSE_ID TOTAL_FEES
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ---------- ----------
Bachelor of Information Technology (Honours) in Internet Technology                                       14       1728
Bachelor of Information Technology (Honours) in Internet Technology                                       15       1353
Bachelor of Information Technology (Honours) in Internet Technology                                       13       1800
Bachelor of Information Technology (Honours) in Internet Technology                                       12       1184

SQL> SELECT SUM(cost) from courses where course_id = 14 or course_id = 15 or course_id = 13 or course_id = 12;

 SUM(COST)
----------
      2219
```

//// after remove the c.cost and group by c.cost

```
TITLE                                                                                                TOTAL_FEES
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ----------
Bachelor of Information Technology (Honours) in Internet Technology                                     6065
```

Comment: What happens if you add DISTINCT in your select statement? Does that change anything?

Comment: It changed nothing ...

Comment: Can you describe what happens when you remove C.cost from the group by and the column in the grid, and only use one of the examples below? I know you said it has the same result, but I know your first problem to resolve is removing C.cost from the Col s and only having the sum(c.cost). You said below the totals were 6,000, but your example looks odd. Can you show the result with the 6,000 listed?

Comment: I pasted the result up there and the total fees after remove the c.cost.  
The result i get from SUM(c.cost) is 6065 (1728 + 1353 + 1184 + 1800) it listed right beside COST'column

But the result i want is 2219 (576 + 451 + 592 + 600)

Thanks for the reply.

Comment: I already solve the problem already, just like the @ryekayo said added the distinct can solve the problem, but is add into the aggregation method. SUM(DISTICT c.cost) Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't include `cost`in the select or the group by as you do not want to compute the sum over groups based on title and cost. Do this instead:

```
SELECT  
    p.title, 
    SUM(c.cost) AS Total_Fees
FROM programmes p 
INNER JOIN courses c 
    ON p.programme_id = c.programme_id 
INNER JOIN class_schedules cs 
    ON c.course_id = cs.course_id AND c.semester = 4
INNER JOIN class_enrollments ce 
    ON cs.schedule_id = ce.schedule_id 
INNER JOIN students s 
    ON ce.student_id = s.student_id AND s.student_id = '13WAR1001'  
GROUP BY p.title;
```

Comment: Ya. i did this before, i added the group by cost is to show the data to you that each of them just few hundreds ... but i sum it up , it will become 6000+. The code is exact like yours. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you have c.cost in the `GROUP BY` and you are doing the SUM aggregation on c.cost column

you need to remove the `cost` column from group by and use only title and also remove cost column from select.

```
GROUP BY p.title
```

Comment: Ya.. i did this before, but still getting the wrong result. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are grouping by c.cost, which means you are grouping by the cost of each row (and the SUM would really just show the cost). If you want to sum for each title you should have the following:

```
Select  p.title, SUM(c.cost) as Total_Fees
    from programmes p Inner Join courses c
        ON p.programme_id = c.programme_id 
    Inner join class_schedules cs
        ON c.course_id = cs.course_id AND c.semester = 4
    Inner join class_enrollments ce
        ON cs.schedule_id = ce.schedule_id 
    Inner Join students s
        ON ce.student_id = s.student_id and s.student_id = '13WAR1001'  
    GROUP BY p.title;
```

Comment: Ya.. i did this before, but still getting the wrong result. i comment at top there already. Thanks.